# How to find out which key is conflicting when using the replaceUnique method?

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-persistent

I'm using the [`replaceUnique` method](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.9/persistent-2.6.1/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:replaceUnique), which has return type of `ReaderT backend m (Maybe (Unique record))`. My database table has two unique fields and if uniqueness is violated, I want to find out which key is conflicting. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with this code:

```
case unique of
  UniqueEmail _ -> -- email is conflicting
  UniqueDisplayName _ -> -- displayName is conflicting
```

where `unique` is `Unique record` and `UniqueEmail _` and `UniqueDisplayName _` are uniqueness  constraints.